# PHP Column count doesn't match

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to run an SQL query in PHP.. using this below code:

```
$sql="INSERT into members (forename, surname, dob_day, dob_month, dob_year, gender, address, invested, patrol_type, patrol, dr_address, 

parent1_contact1_title, parent1_contact1_forename, parent1_contact1_surname, parent1_contact1_email, parent1_contact1_address, parent1_contact1_home, parent1_contact1_mobile, parent1_contact1_other, 

parent1_contact2_title, parent1_contact2_forename, parent1_contact2_surname, parent1_contact2_email, parent1_contact2_address, parent1_contact2_home, parent2_contact1_mobile, parent1_contact2_other, 

parent2_contact1_title, parent1_contact1_forename, parent1_contact1_surname, parent1_contact1_email, parent1_contact1_address, parent1_contact1_home, parent1_contact1_mobile, parent1_contact1_other, 

parent1_contact2_title, parent1_contact2_forename, parent1_contact2_surname, parent1_contact2_email, parent1_contact2_address, parent1_contact2_home, parent2_contact1_mobile, parent1_contact2_other

) values ('".addslashes($_POST["forename"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["surname"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["dob_day"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["dob_month"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["dob_year"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["gender"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["address"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["invested"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["patrol_type"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["patrol"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["dr_address"])."', 

'".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_title"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_forename"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_surname"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_email"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_address"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_home"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_mobile"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_other"])."', 

'".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_title"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_forename"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_surname"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_email"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_address"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_home"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_mobile"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_other"])."', 

'".addslashes($_POST["parent2_contact2_title"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_forename"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_surname"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_email"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_address"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_home"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_mobile"])."', '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_other"])."'

) ";
```

but i am getting an error saying: `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

i cannot find where the error is - can anyone find this?

Comment: Output the resulting string (after substitution) and count columns (column list vs values list)

Comment: count your values(...) against column names

Comment: Oh... My eyes...

Comment: Your table has columns with the same name?

Comment: Best option is to add another 500 columns and values, and update your question then.

Comment: Remember... arrays start counting at zero (0), not one (1)!

Comment: @djot whats that supposed to mean?

Comment: This is a complete useless question that you could debug on your own. Just remove ALL columns and values. Then add only the first column/value combination. Next, step by step some more data/values, until you get your expected result. Learn how to debug your own code.

Comment: You have 5 lines for inserting and 4 with the values. Here is the fault.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your query into a text editor. I split it in lines using the comma as a delimiter and  I have 43 columns and 35 values.
**Use fewer columns in your tables and split the records in generalized patterns, like this:**

```
  Table students:
    id, forename, surname, details, parent1_id, parent2_id, etc..
  Table parents:
    id (used in table students), name, contact details, etc..
```

Comment: Thank you Ollie. English isn't native to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query has these columns more than once:

```
parent1_contact2_title, parent1_contact2_forename, parent1_contact2_surname, parent1_contact2_email, parent1_contact2_address, parent1_contact2_home, parent2_contact1_mobile, parent1_contact2_other
```

But don't appear in the query twice. Hence the column count that you have specified is different from the values you supply.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in column names, some of them are duplicated:

```
$sql="INSERT into members (forename, surname, dob_day, dob_month, dob_year, gender, address, invested, patrol_type, patrol, dr_address, 

parent1_contact1_title, parent1_contact1_forename, parent1_contact1_surname, parent1_contact1_email, parent1_contact1_address, parent1_contact1_home, parent1_contact1_mobile, parent1_contact1_other, 

parent1_contact2_title, parent1_contact2_forename, parent1_contact2_surname, parent1_contact2_email, parent1_contact2_address, parent1_contact2_home, parent2_contact1_mobile, parent1_contact2_other, 

parent2_contact1_title, parent1_contact1_forename, parent1_contact1_surname, parent1_contact1_email, parent1_contact1_address, parent1_contact1_home, parent1_contact1_mobile, parent1_contact1_other, 

parent1_contact2_title, parent1_contact2_forename, parent1_contact2_surname, parent1_contact2_email, parent1_contact2_address, parent1_contact2_home, parent2_contact1_mobile, parent1_contact2_other

)
```

for example `parent1_contact1_forename` is duplicated, fix column names to relevant

Answer (score 0):

This is because the number of columns in your table and the number values you supplied in the table is different. The errors says that the number of columns specified in the sql statement donot match the number of values supplied.

For e.g if i have a table with name ***test*** and columns as follows:
1). id
2). name
3). age
4). Sex

Now lets create insert data in this table

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","dbName");
if(!$con)
die();
$res = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO test(id,name,age,sex) VALUES(abc,xyz,pqr)");
//the query statement will generate an error similar to your's because the number
//of parameters to be filled does not match the values supplied
```

Answer (score 0):

These are your database fields:

```
$sql="INSERT into members (
forename, 
surname, 
dob_day, 
dob_month, 
dob_year, 
gender, 
address, 
invested, 
patrol_type, 
patrol, 
dr_address, 
parent1_contact1_title, 
parent1_contact1_forename, 
parent1_contact1_surname, 
parent1_contact1_email, 
parent1_contact1_address, 
parent1_contact1_home, 
parent1_contact1_mobile, 
parent1_contact1_other, 
parent1_contact2_title, 
parent1_contact2_forename, 
parent1_contact2_surname, 
parent1_contact2_email, 
parent1_contact2_address, 
parent1_contact2_home, 
parent2_contact1_mobile, 
parent1_contact2_other, 
parent2_contact1_title, 
parent1_contact1_forename, 
parent1_contact1_surname, 
parent1_contact1_email, 
parent1_contact1_address, 
parent1_contact1_home, 
parent1_contact1_mobile, 
parent1_contact1_other, 
parent1_contact2_title, 
parent1_contact2_forename, 
parent1_contact2_surname, 
parent1_contact2_email, 
parent1_contact2_address, 
parent1_contact2_home, 
parent2_contact1_mobile, 
parent1_contact2_other
```

These are the values your are trying to store:

```
'".addslashes($_POST["forename"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["surname"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["dob_day"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["dob_month"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["dob_year"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["gender"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["address"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["invested"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["patrol_type"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["patrol"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["dr_address"])."',
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_title"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_forename"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_surname"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_email"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_address"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_home"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_mobile"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact1_other"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_title"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_forename"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_surname"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_email"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_address"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_home"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_mobile"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_other"])."',
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent2_contact2_title"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_forename"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_surname"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_email"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_address"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_home"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_mobile"])."', 
 '".addslashes($_POST["parent1_contact2_other"])."'
```

Either your copy/paste has gone haywire or your database structure needs to be reviewed due to a lot of duplicate data.